# phpmyadmin shows this error about utf8mb

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

I have xampp in Ubuntu
today when I wanted to use phpmyadmin i see this error in my browser:

> Warning: htmlspecialchars(): charset `utf8mb4' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8 in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/Error_Handler.class.php on
>   line 152
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars(): charset `utf8mb4' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8 in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/Error_Handler.class.php on
>   line 152
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars(): charset `utf8mb4' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8 in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/Error_Handler.class.php on
>   line 152
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars(): charset `utf8mb4' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8 in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/Error_Handler.class.php on
>   line 152
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars(): charset `utf8mb4' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8 in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/Error_Handler.class.php on
>   line 152
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars(): charset `utf8mb4' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8 in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/Error_Handler.class.php on
>   line 152
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars(): charset `utf8mb4' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8 in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/Error_Handler.class.php on
>   line 152
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars(): charset `utf8mb4' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8 in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/Error_Handler.class.php on
>   line 152
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars(): charset `utf8mb4' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8 in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/Error_Handler.class.php on
>   line 152
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars(): charset `utf8mb4' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8 in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/Error_Handler.class.php on
>   line 152
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars(): charset `utf8mb4' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8 in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/Error_Handler.class.php on
>   line 152
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars(): charset `utf8mb4' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8 in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/Error_Handler.class.php on
>   line 152
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars(): charset `utf8mb4' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8 in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/Error_Handler.class.php on
>   line 152
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars(): charset `utf8mb4' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8 in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/Error_Handler.class.php on
>   line 152
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars(): charset `utf8mb4' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8 in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/Error_Handler.class.php on
>   line 152

http://axbabak.ir/uploads/e733.png
and last database a built was :
http://axbabak.ir/uploads/e734.png

Comment: i update my phpMyAdmin and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

`utf8mb4` was not available until MySQL 5.5.3.  Upgrade.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version';`